# android Spinner: get the item selected before onItemSected was called

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a list of spinners created dynamically in a view.When  a spinner is clicked it returns me the currently selected item. Is there any way that i can get the item that was there before this selection?

Is any other event possible except onItemSelected()?

Comment: I think you will be able to know the default value the spinners could have from the values you set to them.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong answer, question misinterpretation**

When your `onItemSelected()` is called, you are given a `position` argument. You can use `position - 1` to know the position of the element before the one selected. If you have a **corresponding** array of elements with similar positioning of your spinner elements, then `corresponding_spinner_array[position-1]` should give you your desired element.

**After question reframing**

Why not just remember every selection in a single variable?

**Example updated:**

```
    String[] items = {"a","b","c"};
    String selectedItem;
    /*get your spinner element from your XML layout*/
    /*or if you already have access to it, no need for this*/
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

    spin.setAdapter(aa);

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
     long id) {
          selectedItem = items[position];     
      }
```

Comment: this is not what im looking for, i want the item in the spinner that was there previously and got changed when i selected a new one

Comment: Why don't you just remember every selection? Please reframe your question to specify what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

please look at this code:

```
Spinner sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.type_spinner);
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

this is method for your selected spinner values:

if you not any select value so by default selected first value

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long arg3) {

    String main = (int) parent.getSelectedItemId();

    Log.e("Spinner Value",main);

}
```

Comment: This is giving me the same output as if i had given: String main=position

Answer (score 0):

probably not, you have to maintain your own value. The AdapterView does have an `mOldSelectedPosition` field, but it is not accessible.